# How to call setState without any triggering events?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update the value of a counter variable after some fixed time indefinitely. Here is my code:

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      myCount: 1    
    };
  }
  
  // Update state after every 15 seconds.
  setTimeout(function(){
     this.setState({myCount: this.state.myCount + 1});
  }, 15000);
}
```

However, I get error about unexpected token with this component. How can I set state within the class properly without using any event listeners?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to put your `setTimeout` within your constructor ?

Comment: @Weedoze I get `this.state` is undefined error.

Comment: You're trying to call a function from a class body. Do it in a `componentDidMount` method

Comment: @Weedoze - The constructor of a React component isn't the right place to start a timed operation.

Comment: i agree with @DustInCompetent, call it in the componentDidMount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `setTimeout` is at the top level of the `class` body where properties, the constructor, and methods are expected. You can't put arbitrary code there. (Though you could *could* have a property initializer; not a good idea in this case, though.)

Put it in [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount); and be sure to saved the timer handle (on the instance, usually) and clear the timer in `componentWillUnmount` so it doesn't fire if the component is unmounted before the timer callback occurs:

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            myCount: 1,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Update state after every 15 seconds.
        this.timerHandle = setTimeout(() => {                   // ****
            this.setState((previousState) => {                  // ****
                return { myCount: previousState.myCount + 1 };  // ****
            });                                                 // ****
        }, 15000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearTimeout(this.timerHandle);
    }
}
```

Side note: Notice the changes on the `****` lines above

- I replaced your traditional function with an arrow function so it closes over `this`.
- I changed your callback to use the callback version of `setState`, which is generally best when setting state based on existing state.

> ...after some fixed time indefinitely.

A `setTimeout` callback will only occur once. You may want `setInterval` if you want the counter updated every 15 seconds. Or alternatively, start a new `setTimeout` when the callback runs, like this:

```
startCounterTimer() {
    // Update state after every 15 seconds.
    this.timerHandle = setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState((previousState) => {
            this.startCounterTimer(); // ***
            return { myCount: previousState.myCount + 1 };
        });
    }, 15000);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.startCounterTimer();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @TJ Crowder. :) I used setTimeout() with function components for updates as it called the function again and again automatically. Does that not happen with classes? I am very new to React so don't fully understand how it works.

Comment: @RealNoob - The top level of a function component is basically the body of the `render` method of a `class` component, which is why you got repeated updates -- every update triggered a state change, which caused the function component to be called again with the updated state, which scheduled the next timer call. (That's not actually how you should do it in a function component, though it mostly works.) The closest equivalent to that would be to schedule the next timeout from the timer callback. I've updated the answer to show an example of doing that.